# webpack 4 worker-loader + MiniCssExtractPlugin = Callback was already called

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I've run into a really puzzling issue.

My webpack config was working fine until... I created a library containing antd components.  The library is imported via my worker (and elsewhere) and the library also needs to be included in the babel-loader since the antd component styles used by the library aren't being bundled otherwise.  I'm not using webpack in the library.  Only the client project.

If I remove worker-loader, the build works.  If I remove MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, the build works.  Of course, these have the obvious issues at runtime.

Something about including both of them blows things up with:

```
/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:16
    throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
    ^

Error: Callback was already called.
    at throwError (/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:16:11)
    at /project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Here's my setup:

```
webpack@4.41.2
mini-css-extract-plugin@0.8.0
worker-loader@2.0.0
```

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.worker\.ts$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['babel-loader', 'worker-loader'],
  },
  {
    // Include ts, tsx, js, and jsx files.
    test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/my-custom-library'),
    ],
    loader: 'babel-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(css|less)$/,
    use: [
      { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
      { loader: 'css-loader' },
      {
        loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
        options: {
          modifyVars: {
            // modify antd theme variables
            // https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less
            'primary-color': '#5f9cd1',
            'link-color': '#1890ff',
          },
          javascriptEnabled: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
],
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!